# Google Maps not showing all diacritics on the tiles

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need Google Map to show the streets names with diacritics. I use the script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=ro"></script>
```

But some street names are showing names with diacritics, some are not. Do you know why?

Screenshot: http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/2664/capture1v.jpg

Comment: Check out this ROADMAP, TERRAIN, HYBRID in Map type

Comment: I use google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

Comment: check for HYBRID,,it will be your result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the little squares in the middle of words, then that's a bug in the tile creation where the required character is not included in the font or has been wrongly specified.

Best thing to do is to report a formal issue in the [Issues list](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list). It would be extremely fiddly to do anything about it yourself by covering the square with a character image -- but you could do that (eg add each letter required as a specially-designed marker controlled by the marker manager for zoom).